# Split a specific part of data into single line in a file in shell script

Tags: shell

I have a file which has below data, It has several MQ Queue statistics;

**QueueName= 'TEST1'**

  CreateDate= '2009-10-30'
  CreateTime= '13.45.40'
  QueueType= Predefined
  QueueDefinitionType= Local
  QMinDepth= 0
  QMaxDepth= 0
  **QueueName= 'TEST2'**

  CreateDate= '2009-10-30'
  CreateTime= '13.51.12'
  QueueType= Predefined
  QueueDefinitionType= Local
  QMinDepth= 0
  QMaxDepth= 6

My output should be as below, each queue details should be displayed in a single line delimited by space,

QueueName= 'TEST1' CreateDate= '2009-10-30' CreateTime= '13.45.40' QueueType= Predefined 
QueueDefinitionType= Local QMinDepth= 0 QMaxDepth= 0
  QueueName= 'TEST2' CreateDate= '2009-10-30' CreateTime= '13.51.12' QueueType= Predefined 
QueueDefinitionType= Local QMinDepth= 0 QMaxDepth= 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Output-Separators
"1" is an awk idiom to print everything

```
awk -v ORS=' ' '/^QueueName=/{print "\n"} 1' foo.txt
```